# Workaround script for ARRAYFORMULA with INDIRECT

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, automation, formula, add-on

After wasting way too much time reading support forms, it seems like there’s no current way to use ARRAYFORMULA and INDIRECT together in Google Sheets.

I’m currently trying to pull information from tabs based on an array of tab names.

Without a workaround formula for arrays in Google Sheets, I’m turning to making custom functions with Apps Script. I’ve perused 3 branches to no luck, so I’ll take any idea at this point. I’ve tried:

1. Creating a new indirect formula that can handle being used in ARRAYFORMULA
2. Creating an evaluate function that can take text and turn it into a formula
3. Creating an indirect formula that can be passed arrays of sheet names

If anybody knows of any scripts or plugins that can even remotely do this, please share it.

I can share my attempts at the custom functions if requested, but they’re most likely detrimental to the topic given how bad I am at writing efficiently in JavaScript.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: Without seeing your actual spreadsheet, layout(s), data, data types, etc., or knowing your end goal, it's hard to comment as to a solution. However, it's important to understand what an array *is*, as that understanding addresses why certain function which themselves act as arrays cannot have another array dimension added. In simplest terms, think of a single array (whether specified as such with ArrayFormula, or built virtually within curly brackets or occurring as the result of an built-in array function) as a 2D (x,y) array. Attempting to apply another array would be a 3D (x,y,z) array.

Answer (score 0):

They're basically trying to do this:
Given this example table

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Group 1 | A1:A |
| 2 | Group 2 | A1:A |
| 3 | Group 4 | B3:B |
| 4 | Another Group | A2:A |

1)

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA("=INDIRECT('"&A1:A&"'!"&B1:B&")")
    =ARRAYFORMULA(EVALUATE(C1:C)) // Would turn previous text to formula, created through Apps Script
```

2. 

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(BETTERINDIRECT("'"&A1:A&"'!"&B1:B&"")) // text makes make 'name'!range
// BETTERINDIRECT would be a Apps Script function that works with ArrayFormula
```

3. 

```
    =INDIRECTARRAY("'"&A1:A&"'!"&B1:B&"")) // a custom function that accepts an array of entries
// Would need to be made through apps script
```

All's they are asking is if anybody has designed any addons or written code that could do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple App Script to do what you ask for.

```
/**
 * Returns an array consisting of the concatenation of the given range from all sheets, skipping a specified number of initial sheets.
 *
 * @param {string} cell_range - The range to be taken from all sheets.
 * @param {number} [first=1] - The number of initial sheets to skip.
 * @param {boolean} [horizontal=false] - Concatenate horizontally or vertically.
 * @param {boolean} [name=false] - Add sheet name as the first column or row depending on horizontal.
 * @returns {Array<Array<any>>} The concatenated data.
 */
function rangeFromAllSheets(cell_range, first=1, horizontal=false, name=false) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var result = [];

  // Loop over all sheets and get the data from the specified range
  for (var i = first; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var data = sheet.getRange(cell_range).getValues();

    if (name) {
      if (!horizontal) {
        // If concatenating horizontally and name is true, add sheet name as the first row
        data.unshift([sheet.getName()]);
      } else {
        // If concatenating vertically and name is true, add sheet name as the first column
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          data[j].unshift(sheet.getName());
        }
      }
    }

    if (!horizontal) {
      // Concatenate the data horizontally
      result = result.concat(data);
    } else {
      // Concatenate the data vertically
      if (result.length === 0) {
        result = data;
      } else {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
          result[j] = result[j].concat(data[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

You can use it with:

```
=rangeFromAllSheets("E1:F1")
```